# Parsing algorithm that parses the string

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, context-free-grammar

I would like to preface this by saying this is a homework assignment for me and I'm looking for some help with it. I think using The Recursive Descent Parsing and stack java code can solve this exercise but I do not know how should I compare the languages. The question is:

Let L1 and L2 be two languages accepted by the LL(1) grammars G1 and
G2, respectively.
- Write a parsing algorithm that parses the strings of the form ss'ts"  where
s,s',s" belong to L1 and t belongs to L2.

---

```
    stack 1.push (StartSymbol) 
LA1=input.nextToken () 
repeat 
X1=stack1. Pop () 
if X1 ε T1 then 
if X1= LA1 then 
Stack1.pop () 
LA1=input.nextToken (), 
else 
error () 
end if 
else 
if M [X1.LA] = X1-> Y1 …. Yn then 
stack1.pop() 
push Yn …… Y1 on to stack, with Y1 on top 
add X-> Y1…. Yn to parse tree 
else 
error () 
end if 
end if 
until LA = EOF
```

Comment: If S1 and S2 are the start symbols of the two grammars, just build a new grammar with start simple S by combining all the rules of G1 and G2 (renaming symbols so there are no conflicts) and adding the production `S -> S1 S1 S2 S1`. This grammar might not be LL(1). You need a way to make it so. Showing that's always possible is the trick. Then build a parser for the new grammar.

Comment: I think when the strings are coming from 2 different languages , first, I should be sure that each string belongs to its language. second, be sure that the result of the parsing algorithm parses the ss'ts" correctly. I do not have any idea about how should I solve this after this part